# In CSS is there a selector for referencing a specific input type that also has a class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Basically I want a CSS selector that grabs all input[type="text"] but that also has a class "some-class".

Both of the following don't seem to be working for me:

```
input[type="text"] .some-class {}    /* doesn't work */

.some-class input[type="text"] {}    /* doesn't work */
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You want `input.some-class[type="text"]`

`.some-class input` looks for input tags that are descendants of `.some-class`.

`input.some-class` does the reverse.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  I also just discovered a second ago that input[type="text"][class~="some-class"] also works but I like your solution better because it is cleaner.

Comment: @Art Geigel: It is better because it's using the right tool for the job... if you know you can use a class selector to select by class, then just use the class selector!

Answer (score 35):

```
    input[type="text"].some-class {
    ....
     }
```

with no space between "input[type="text"]" and ".some-class" will work..

input[type="text"]-space in between is the problem-.some-class {}