# Using select for different Drop Down Lists

Tags: html, css

Any ideas on how to use a select in css but will only change the desired DDL and not all of them.

Example : 
HTML:

```
   <div style="position: relative; float: left;  margin-left: 12px;">
             <select class="theCombo">
                 <option value="" class="theCombo">&nbsp; Choose...</option>
                <option value="1">&nbsp; Visa</option>
                <option value="2">&nbsp; Neteller</option>
             </select>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.theCombo,select { /* Incorrect : changing all selects of the ddl*/
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;  
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #E4EBED;
    border-radius: 3px;
  width: 157px;
 /* height: 32px;
  line-height: 25px;*/
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #333333 !important; 
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAKCAMAAACdQr5nAAAAPFBMVEXn6+P3+/L3+/L0+O/3+/L3+/L3+/L3+/L3+/L3+/L3+/L3+/L0+O/n6+Pq7eX3+/IAAAD2+vHz9+73+/KWthK3AAAAEXRSTlP0MXqqRZEIkAlEMnmr8+IRAJig9poAAABYSURBVHjadY5JDoAwDAMLdF+T+v9/hYIqFFDnFHtysKIlio72ppaFQgkzhAKpwM6O0zqGVHsHaiTaKtCTUBTvLj0fUpE3jAs2nqQa6AIo/R0/V+dGP7XkBDn1D5sPSFgFAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;

}
```

Comment: Your rule is applying to `.theCombo` and all `select` lists. Either drop `,select` from the rule, or change it to `select.theCombo`

Comment: @LuanaFarrugia - please remember to accept answers that correctly answered your question by clicking the check mark next to them.  You can upvote as many answers as you'd like, but you can only accept one.  This helps future users with similar problems to yours quickly get to the best answer.  Welcome to the forum - and best of luck!

Comment: @LuanaFarrugia no worries - you get points for accepting answers to your own questions, so it helps you, too.  But, more importantly, it'll help the future users.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want:

```
select.theCombo
```

for your CSS selector.  This grabs all select elements and filters by "theCombo" class.

[In CSS is there a selector for referencing a specific input type that also has a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243088/in-css-is-there-a-selector-for-referencing-a-specific-input-type-that-also-has-a)